# Buildkit Issue - permissions?

Tags: civicrm-buildkit

I've encountered a problem (only recently) with buildkit, where when it comes time for me to run:

*~/buildkit/bin/civibuild install "civi46" --url "http://civi46" --admin-pass "password" --web-root "/var/www/civi46"*

I get

*++ CMS_DB_HOSTPORT=127.0.0.1:3306
++ pushd /var/www/civi46
++ '[' -f sites/default/settings.php ']'
++ rm -f sites/default/settings.php
rm: cannot remove `sites/default/settings.php': Permission denied*

But when I run

*sudo ~/buildkit/bin/civibuild install "civi46" --url "http://civi46" --admin-pass "password" --web-root "/var/www/civi46"*

I get

*+ bower install -f
bower ESUDO         Cannot be run with sudo
Additional error details:
Since bower is a user command, there is no need to execute it with superuser permissions.
If you're having permission errors when using bower without sudo, please spend a few minutes learning more about how your system should work and make any necessary repairs.
http://www.joyent.com/blog/installing-node-and-npm
https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814
You can however run a command with sudo using --allow-root option*

This takes place even if I (shudder) set settings.php to have 777.

Even if I try to install civi manually after that, it is missing the files lang.php and civicrm-version.php.

With these copied from elsewhere, and the correct install details, clicking install results in "cannot lock table civicrm_acl - doesn't exist". Of course it doesn't exist. I need you to create it, silly install.php!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `civibuild` command is designed to run as a regular shell user (e.g. `john`) -- without `root` permissions. The source code should all be owned by the shell-user, and the data files should be owned by a mix of `www-data`/`apache`/`www`/`john`. No files should should be owned by `root`.

The exact errors have varied (depending on the revision and the commands used), so I generally run a search to identify files with errant permissions, e.g.

```
## Searching for files owned by root (or not by john)
find ~/.npm/ ~/.composer/ ~/.drush/ ~/buildkit/ -user root
find ~/.npm/ ~/.composer/ ~/.drush/ ~/buildkit/ ! -user $(whoami)
find ~/.npm/ ~/.composer/ ~/.drush/ ~/buildkit/ ! -user john -a ! -user www-data

## Changing owner from root to john
find ~/.npm/ ~/.composer/ ~/.drush/ ~/buildkit/ -user root -exec chown john {} \;
```

Note that this search covers several folders, including:

- The caches generated by various build tools (eg `npm`, `composer`, `drush`)
- The caches generated by buildkit (eg `~/buildkit/app/tmp`)
- The actual build (eg `~/buildkit/build/mybuild`)

Additionally, if I've recently run `amp config` to change the permission policy, fixing the permissions on existing files can be pretty fiddly. I find easiest to delete the old build (e.g. `civibuild destroy mybuild` or `rm -rf ~/buildkit/build/mybuild`) and then recreate it.

Comment: Thanks Tim - I think that last one might have caused it.

Comment: Also ~/.config and ~/.npm need updating to have you as their owner. I found using civibuild create with the --force parameter helped me out. You shouldn't use sudo when running civibuild create.